# Run python function in shell script

Tags: python, shell

Let's say I want to use a shell script to run a python file, called test.py, which is in a directory called Test in my home directory. I tried the following code, which does not work:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "Starting."

 module load gcc/4.8.2
 module load python/3.4.1

 echo "Modules loaded."

 $HOME/Test/test.py

 exit 0
```

I do not believe that how I am trying to run the program ($HOME/Test/test.py) works. I have not been able to determine how to do this, despite searching for a long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely one of the following, or it may be a combination of both.

The python script is not executable. Fix with:

```
chmod u+x $HOME/Test/test.py
```

The script does not start with a `#!` line pointing to python. Fix that by making this the first line of `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

You can also use a full path instead of using `/usr/bin/env` to use `$PATH` to resolve the name.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Comment: Thanks, after adding "chmod u+x $HOME/Test/test.py" to my program, it created an output file, but it did not include the output of test.py (which simply prints "Hello World"). Am I missing something else? I am using python 3.4.1, so do I need to write "#!/usr/bin/env python3" instead?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env` will just resolve whatever is after it to some full path, so if you use python as `python3`, then yes you would do that. You can also use a full path to the interpreter instead, such as `#!/usr/bin/python3`.